# Explaining outliers in laymen terms

Tags: outliers

I have a presentation coming up where I need to explain what an outlier is to someone with little to no statistical background, as well as explain ways to identify outliers.  So I guess what I am looking for help with is

1) How to explain outliers in laymen terms?

2) What are "good" ways to identify outliers?

Comment: (2) is too broad: it takes [entire books](https://books.google.com/books/about/Outliers_in_statistical_data.html?id=B44QAQAAIAAJ) to answer it.

Comment: @whuber I suppose I meant more so could you name a few standard approaches that an audience could understand and appreciate

Comment: Will you also deal with the more challenging element 3): "How to deal with outliers in my analysis"?

Comment: (2) is too broad. See [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Robust-Statistics-Ricardo-A-Maronna/dp/0470010924) for a good introduction. For (1) I usually write: "Observations that are inconsistent with the (multivariate) pattern of the majority of the data."

Answer (score -1):

> 1) How to explain outliers in laymen terms?

I think this definition on Wikipedia can't get any simpler. `An outlier is an observation point that is distant from other observations.`

> 2) What are "good" ways to identify outliers?

One which I use very frequently in my models is the [Mahalanobis Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance)

Along with that, there are some other tests through which outliers can be identified:

1. [Chauvenet's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauvenet%27s_criterion): Finds the probability of an outlier to be spurious.
2. [Grubb's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grubbs%27_test_for_outliers): Detect outliers on Univariate data.

Comment: What does "distant from" actually mean?  That would seem to be subjective, broad, and open to wildly differing interpretations. :-)

Comment: @whuber You are right. It depends on a lot of things:  The problem statement, the analyst's perception, the data, etc, etc.

But, here as the OP is explaining the basics to the audience, he shouldn't really worry about that.  The word _distant from_ should give the gist of the definition of outliers (at least as a basic definition.).

Comment: That's fine--but I would like to suggest there is value in maintaining a distinction between an *intuitive characterization* and a *definition*.  You have quoted the former (which is an appropriate response), but not the latter.  From recent experiences in teaching graduate stats students, I would also like to mention that "distant from" is remarkably easy to misinterpret, especially when popular software (such as `lm.plot` in `R`) automatically flags extreme values regardless of *how* distant they are from other observations.